# Is there an easy way to sort an arraylist in this manner?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I'm wondering if there is a way to sort an Arraylist of custom objects to fit the situation explained below? I'm assuming I'll have to write a custom comparator.

Let's say I have an object class that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String status;    //options: Online, Away, Offline
    private String name;      //Person's name
    private Date date;        //Last signed on

    //basic constructor
    public Person() {
        //set default values
    }

    //constructor to set all variables
    public Person(String s, String n, Date d) {
        status = s;
        name = n;
        date = d;
    }

    //setters & getters for each of the fields
}
```

Sorting based on name and date should be fairly easy. However, I'm wondering how I would sort based on the status? I would like to be able to sort my array based on whether the person is currently **online** and also who is **offline**. I'm not too concerned with who is away.

The above class is just an example class. My actual class has a JLabel set an icon based on the status. The `setText()` remains unused. I thought of a possibility of setting the label to values of 0, 1, and 2 and just using a typical integer comparator but I wasn't sure if that was an advised way of doing it.

Surely I'm missing an obvious solution here, so perhaps a comment or link can provide the necessary information. I know there are tons of 'Sort Arraylist' threads here at SO and I've browsed a lot of them. Most of them are just sorting Strings alphabetically or Integers though.

Comment: Status should probably be an Enum.

Comment: See the javadoc for collections on how you sort after you have written your comparator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: @mrhobo I'll read into Enum. With an Enum, I'm assuming I would give them values and sort based on the integer values? Nattyddubbs, I'm currently reading the link.

Comment: What doesn't make sense with the question is that there is no "natural" ordering of status' unless you are using `String` ordering where `Online` > `Offline` > `Away`. With an `Enum` you can define their ordering within the object or just by putting them in the desired "order" in the enum declaration.

Comment: @nattyddubbs Wow, I wasn't aware that putting them in a desired order in the Enum automatically defined it like so. I obviously need to read up on Enums. Thank you. My apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i understand correctly you basically want to sort on 2 fields - the major field is status (so people of the same status are bunched together) and then, whithin each gruop of people with the same status, by name.

a comparator that does this looks like this:

```
 public class CompositePersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {    
    @Override
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
       //1st and foremost - see if they are not of the same status.
       int statusComparison = a.getStatus().compareTo(b.getStatus());
       if (statusComparison!=0) return statusComparison;
       //logical else - same status, sort by name
       return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
 }
```

Comment: You did understand what I'm asking correctly. Thank you for the example, if you don't mind could you explain how that is sorting it? How do I know if it is sorting by Online, Offline, or Away?

Comment: @WilliamShatner - it relies on all properties involved being Comparable to themselves. Integers, Strings and most built-ins are. if you make status into an Enum as suggested above yuo could either make it implement Comparable<Status> on rely on built-in enum comparison (by the order they are written). Strings compare alphabetically. a return value of 0 from a compare() method indicates equality - think of a.compareTo(b) as being "like" a-b in math

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I believe the example above would just sort the strings alphabetically. So I do indeed need to use an Enum (like illustrated by Thorn).

Answer (score 1):

Using enums can be useful here
 `enum MyEnum { ONLINE, AWAY, OFFLINE;}`

Comment: That could actually be a good answer to the question. However, you might want to expand a bit on how this would work.

Comment: Indeed this was a good answer to the question. I agree with Andrew though, I didn't know much about Enums so it would have been great if you had expanded on it like Thorn did. +1 though as you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest we handle the status as an enumerated data type instead of a String where it can only be one of a few strings. This makes it easy to write a readable compareTo method:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
  private Status currentStatus;   
  private String name;      //Person's name
  private Date date;        //Last signed on

  enum Status {ONLINE, AWAY, OFFLINE};

  //basic constructor
  public Person()  {
     //set default values
  }

  //constructor to set all variables
  public Person(Status s, String n, Date d) {
     currentStatus = s;
     name = n;
     date = d;
  }

 /**
  *   Order the Persons first by status where all ONLINE Persons are listed first.
  */
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Person other) {
     if(other.currentStatus == currentStatus)
        return name.compareTo(other.name);

     return currentStatus.ordinal() - other.currentStatus.ordinal();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant example. You are absolutely correct. I will need to change the structure of my class and classes that make use of this variable now.